# Current datagrid item and multibinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, in which I want to change the background of a row according to the values of the ItemSource, so I need to pass the current item, but I don't know how.

I am doing that:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myDataGridBackgroundMultiValueConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.MyProperty01FromDataContext"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.MyProperty02FromDataContext"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.MyProperty03FromDataContext"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="dgdMyGrid" Path="CurrentItem"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>                        
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The DataGrid has as `ItemsSource` a collection of `MyDataClass` (that has many properties) in the `ViewModel`. I need to pass to the converter the MyDataClass with the information of the row.

CurrentItem does not work, because I always receive null.

All the other parameters are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` has no `CurrentItem` property, only `CollectionViews` have, DataGrid has a `SelectedItem`. You should see a [binding error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) because of this as well.

If by current item you mean the data item to which the styled row belongs that would be the `DataContext` of the current row, which can be targeted via `<Binding />`.

Comment: selectedItem was an example. I mean that I want to know the information of the row.

Comment: @Daimroc: Shouldn't that be the `DataContext` of the row? i.e. simply `<Binding />`

Answer (score 0):

Well, finnally, I get the way to pass the dataContext of the row to the converter. I do the following:

```
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ChangeTracker.State, Converter={StaticResource visibilidadFilaBorradaConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ucTareasMatenimientoDataGridBackgroundMultiValueConverter}">
                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.Property01"/>
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.Property02"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.Property03"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="ucPrincipal" Path="DataContext.Property04"/>                                    
                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>                        
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

In the second parameter for the multivalue converter, I use the RelativeSource, to be able to pass the datContext of the row. In this way, I can compare its information with other properties of the principal dataContext of the control.

Comment: As i said, `<Binding />` should do exactly the same without the redundant relative source.